# Accessing FTDI USB to SPI FT232H by COM Port (hypertermial) VCP Driver

Tags: vba, spi

I am studying how to use FDTI FT232H to communicate device through SPI mode. I read the website of FDTI there are a lot code examples of "D2XX" driver. 
But I see there also support "VCP" driver. Does it mean I can use "Hyper terminal" to send and read date from control device?
But I check the datasheet there is no such command list like as "configure mode I2C or SPI", "set clock rate" and "write and send data". 
Do I misunderstand VCP driver meaning? Does anyone know it is possible to use COM (hyperterminal) to communicate FDTI device?

Comment: From what I understand is that /dev/ttyUSB0 (or COMx) is your access to the uart function of that FT232H device. Not for config of its own features.